# Computing the real part of $e^{e^z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z = x + iy$.  Then

$$
e^{e^z} = e^{e^{x + iy}} = e^{e^{x}e^{iy}} =  e^{e^{x} {\left( \cos(y) + i\sin(y) \right)}} = e^{e^x \cos(y) + i e^x \sin(y)} = e^{e^x \cos(y)} e^{i e^x \sin(y)}
$$

so that since

$$
e^{i e^x \sin(y)} = \cos(e^x \sin(y)) + i\ \sin(e^x \sin(y))
$$

we have that

$$
e^{e^z} = e^{e^x \cos(y)} e^{i e^x \sin(y)} = e^{e^x \cos(y)}\cos(e^x \sin(y)) + i\ e^{e^x \cos(y)} \sin(e^x \sin(y))
$$

so that

$$
\Re(e^{e^{z}}) = e^{e^x \cos(y)}\cos(e^x \sin(y))
$$

Is this pretty much all we can say?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Yes -- I apologize for the incomplete post.  I accidentally posted before I was done with it and was trying to edit it to completion as fast as possible.  What I want to ask is (i) am I correct, and (ii) is there anything more we can say?

Comment: @user If your goal is "what is $\Re[e^{e^{x+iy}}]$", then this is the correct answer and nothing more need be said.

Comment: @user1770201 For future reference, you could always edit your post to say that you're still typing the question, and then continue to edit.  Also, I think there's a way for you to delete your answer, edit it, and then undelete it.

Comment: @user1770201 and, as Mario says, you've said all there is to say here.  Well done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuing in that thread:

\begin{align}
e^{e^z} &= e^{e^x \cos y + i e^x \sin y}= e^{e^x \cos y}e^{i e^x \sin y}=e^{e^x \cos y}(\cos(e^x \sin y)+i\sin(e^x \sin y))\\
&=e^{e^x \cos y}\cos(e^x \sin y)+ie^{e^x \cos y}\sin(e^x \sin y).
\end{align}

Thus the real part of $e^{e^{x+iy}}$ is $e^{e^x \cos y}\cos(e^x \sin y)$.