# Computing the real part of $e^z$ when $z=x-jy$

Tags: complex-analysis

I searched for the answer and this post was helpful for me

([Computing the real part of $e^{e^z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/774194/computing-the-real-part-of-eez))

but the case here is that z is different $z=x+jy$ not in my case where $z=x-jy$.

So any help please?

Edited later:

Is there any chance that this is the answer?

$e^z=e^{x-jy}=e^x e^{-jy}=e^x(cos(y)-jsin(y))$

Therefore: Re = $e^x(cos(y))$ ???

Comment: Can you just change sign on $y$ from the $z=x+jy$ case?

Comment: This question is in one of my Differential Equations books and it asks me to find the real part while having had $z$ defined as given above. So don't think i can change the sign to the $z=x+jy$ case. That is my humble opinion. Still not sure though.

Comment: What is $j$? A cubic root of unity or the physicists' notation for the square root of $-1$?

Comment: Yes. Sometimes noted with $i$ instead of $j$

Comment: @Shkodrani Yes you're right, $\mathfrak{R}(e^z)=e^x\cos(y)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$e^z=e^{x-iy}=e^xe^{i(-y)}=e^x\left(\cos(y)-i\sin(y)\right)$$
as we know that:
$$e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Recall that $\forall w\in \mathbb{C}$ $$\Re(w)=\Re(\bar w)$$

and

$$\overline {e^z}=e^{\bar z}$$

indeed

$$e^z=e^{x+iy}=e^xe^{iy}=e^x(\cos y+i\sin y)\implies \overline {e^z}=e^x(\cos y-i\sin y)$$

Comment: @gimusi: Minor error, but can you correct the exponent on the last line? It should be $e^{x+iy}$

Comment: @wintersoldier Yes of course! Thanks for pointing tgst out, Bye